# How can I brew a black lager?

Tags: brewing, lager, schwarzbier

Is a black lager really a lager (in terms of yeast and brewing time)? Can I just throw in whatever would make a good stout but use lager yeast? If not, then how much play is there to the recipe?

I've got a little bit of experience brewing ales, mainly stout and brown ale. Just a few months ago I tried my first experiment, deviating a little from a recipe in my choice of malts and yeast, but still using a malt extract for my primary malt. I have zero experience with brewing lager.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Homebrewing, and should be moved to homebrew.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So, how can I get it moved? Still curious about this one.

Comment: I think a moderator has to do it, since Homebrewing did not appear as a potential target site when I flagged this for moving. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site). That said, I think it's fine if you just copy the question and post it as a new question on Homebrewing. You'll want to make sure your question hasn't already been answered on that site, but I did a quick check and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

A black lager, or perhaps a schwarzbier, really is a lager.  Aside from the difference in the fermentation process, there will be some difference in your base ingredients, as a schwarzbier will focus less on the chocolates or coffee flavor of a stout.

I suspect you may find significantly more information in homebrew.stackexchange.com, as hunse suggests.  We would love to go into all sorts of detail over there!